# incompatible pointer types sending 'nsnumber *' to parameter of type 'nsstring *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsstring, nsnumber

I am trying to have an alert box show a randomly generated number, but no matter how I play around, I haven't gotten it working yet and I am still searching around the web.  Here's what I have:

```
ticketNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %100000];

PFObject *people = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"People"];
people[@"ticket"] = ticketNumber;
people[@"photo"] = chosenImage;
[people saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // The object has been saved.
        UIAlertView *ticketNumberView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ticket Number"
                                                                   message:ticketNumber
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK, I got it."
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [ticketNumberView show];
```

However, the error I am receiving is "incompatible pointer types sending 'nsnumber *' to parameter of type 'nsstring *'".  The app still compiles and runs on my iPhone, but it freezes and crashes when it gets down to around this code area.  What do I have wrong here?

Comment: You are taking NSString value as NSNumber... You have to convert string value to number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
[ticketNumber stringValue];
```

the method `stringValue` is used to express `ticketNumber` as human readable string.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[ticketNumber stringValue]` to convert NSNumber to NSString, and use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to show the alert view.

```
[alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the UIAlertView Class Reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/message) the "message" property is defined as type NSString. So, attempting to send "ticketNumber" which is an object of type NSNumber (which inherits from NSValue, not NSString) into the message property of UIAlertView makes the compiler complain. To use this initializer, first convert the ticketNumber to NSString with the `[ticketNumber stringValue]` method call noted in other answers.